# Is building the Linux Kernel with -fno-inline supported?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to diagnose a NULL pointer access in the Linux Kernel:

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000100
IP: [<c1145647>] kmem_cache_alloc+0x47/0x150
```

However, `kmem_cache_alloc` is full of inline functions. In order to pinpoint the exact location of the NULL pointer access, I need to build the Kernel without inlined functions. I know it's not a good idea to build the Kernel with -fno-inline, but it's just for diagnostic purposes.

So I have added a few options to `KBUILD_CFLAGS` in the Makefile:

```
-fno-default-inline
-fno-inline
-fno-inline-small-functions
-fno-indirect-inlining
-fno-inline-functions-called-once
```

Unfortunately, `-fno-inline` causes a build error, tripped by the `BUILD_BUG` macro:

```
mm/filemap.c:338:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘HPAGE_PMD_NR’
page_ref_sub(page, HPAGE_PMD_NR);
```

Caused by:

```
./include/linux/huge_mm.h:161:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘BUILD_BUG’
#define HPAGE_PMD_SHIFT ({ BUILD_BUG(); 0; })
```

Apparently, we're not supposed to use `HPAGE_PMD_SHIFT` when `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` is not configured in, but `HPAGE_PMD_NR` does just that through `HPAGE_PMD_ORDER`. And both are available regardless of `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE`:

```
#define HPAGE_PMD_ORDER (HPAGE_PMD_SHIFT-PAGE_SHIFT)
#define HPAGE_PMD_NR (1<<HPAGE_PMD_ORDER)
```

My question is: Should it be possible to build the Kernel with -fno-inline?

I'm wondering, because to my understanding this error should trip regardless of setting -fno-inline or not. And this code is awfully close to the code I'm currently diagnosing.

Update: When configuring in `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE`, everything compiles, but it doesn't link. I think I can fix that with a bit of elbow grease, but it's no real solution, because `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` cannot be used in conjunction with `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL`, which our application depends upon.

Comment: Can you better explain the link between `-fno-inline` and the build failure? Because I'm not seeing how `-fno-inline` is causing the failure.

Comment: You could try to compile only the object file with the relevant function you try to debug with `-fno-inline`. Just build the kernel as usual, then compile the single object file by hand and then link the kernel together.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I don't see it either, but there is a 1:1 correlation. With `-fno-inline` I get build errors like the one posted. Without, it builds flawlessly. There's really no other difference. If there's anything specific I can try or you want to know, I'd be happy to oblige.

Comment: @Ctx: Good suggestion. I haven't thought about that, but coincidentally, mm is also the subsystem I want to debug.

Comment: It's not only `BUILD_BUG()` macro which will fail to compile. So, in general the answer is no, you can't do that.

Comment: But looking into the question it seems you choose wrong approach to hunt the bug. If you able to build kernel with debug information in you don't need to uninline functions. Just use tools you have, like `addr2line`.

Comment: @0andriy: I will give `addr2line` a go when I'm back in the office on Monday. I hope it will get me closer than `objdump -dS` did, but I don't have high hopes.

Comment: I am probably missing something obvious here, but in my local tree (git from a few weeks ago), that code is in an "if (PageTransHuge(page)..." block.  PageTransHuge() is an inline only defined if CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE is, but it looks like it is called unconditionally.  So it looks to me (but I probably missed something) as though the non-CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE is broken.  What kernel are you using?

Comment: @michaeljt: Exactly my point! Or at least I'm missing the same thing. The way I read the code, `BUILD_BUG()` should trip if `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` is configured out. But it doesn't, unless I try to build with `-fno-inline`. So I think something is broken too. The more because of the NULL-pointer accesses in MM...

Comment: @0andriy: I had to improvise a little, because the debug Kernel doesn't seem to reproduce this problem. But I have an assembly clipping with a matching backtrace. Comparing the assembly code with the assembly clipping I have the backtrace off, gave me an instruction that made `addr2line` report to be this function:  
    static inline void *get_freepointer(struct kmem_cache *s, void *object)  
    {  
     return *(void **)(object + s->offset);  
    }

Answer (score 1):

The question is years old but still relevant to me, so I write my experience here and hope it helps others. I successfully compile the `v6.1.22` kernel with `-fno-inline` after adding enough `__always_inline` patches.

Many codes (including the one discussed in the above comments) implicitly rely on the coincidence that certain functions will be inlined and evaluated to constants by the compiler at compile time. For example, consider the following code from `v6.3.1` tree. The following code could compile no matter `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` is set or not.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3.1/source/mm/shmem.c#L1070

```c
    if (shmem_is_huge(inode, 0, false, NULL, 0))
        stat->blksize = HPAGE_PMD_SIZE;
```

But `HPAGE_PMD_SIZE` is only defined when `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` is enabled and triggers a build time error otherwise.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3.1/source/include/linux/huge_mm.h#L299

```
#define HPAGE_PMD_SIZE ({ BUILD_BUG(); 0; })
```

It compiles because when `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` is not enabled, `shmem_is_huge` is defined as a function that always returns false and is automatically inlined and evaluated to false at compile time, making the whole branch eliminated by the compiler.

```
bool shmem_is_huge(struct inode *inode, pgoff_t index, bool shmem_huge_force,
           struct mm_struct *mm, unsigned long vm_flags)
{
    return false;
}
```

When `-fno-inline` flag is set, `shmem_is_huge` is not inlined, so the branch is not eliminated, making the compilation fail. We can fix it by adding `__always_inline` in the function definition, which inlines functions ignoring the `-fno-inline` flag. But we must fix hundreds of similar issues before compiling the kernel successfully.